# Undefined type 'Tymon\JwTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject'

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I installed this package:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth  "^1.0"
```

Then ran:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

And then:

```
 php artisan jwt:secret
```

I also added this to the app.php config file:

```
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

The commands ran without errors. However, following the documentation I'm trying to implement the JWTSubject interface on the User model. However like this:

```
use Tymon\JwTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
```

The JWTSubject is underlined with red and it says:

```
Undefined type 'Tymon\JwTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject'.
```

Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks

Comment: Considering the amount of open issues and lack of commits for like the past year or 2 perhaps it's a good idea to use another package. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: Thanks, but it seems also that is very used for having jwt working. Do you recommend some other?

Answer (score 1):

It worked with these commands, ignoring the platform requirements:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs

 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"

php artisan jwt:secret
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is not loaded in autoload_classmap.php
You should do `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

I opened "vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Contracts\JWTSubject.php" and that error suddenly fixed.

I don't know why, but it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's the PHP Intelephense extension in VS Code, I uninstalled it and that was the error. I had already had problems with this extension before

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34716649)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).